# Nested classes and dynamically invocations issues

Tags: c#, reflection, nested-class

I have the following scenario:

```
public class Restriction
{
    public string RestrictionName { get; set; }
    public bool Eval(decimal Value2)
    {
        Type typeRestriction = Type.GetType(RestrictionName);
        return (bool)typeRestriction.InvokeMember("Eval",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
            null,
            null,
            new object[] { this, Value2 });
    }


    /* Nested Classes */
    class A
    {
        public static bool Eval(Restriccion r, decimal value)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }

    class B
    {
        public static bool Eval(Restriccion r, decimal value)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

When I Try:

```
    Restriction r = new Restriction();
    r.RestrictionName = "A";
    r.Value = 15;
    r.Eval(16);
```

I get `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
Debug shows me that  `typeRestriction` is null. Why? Are nested classes have special treatment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The types `A` and `B` are nested types in this scenario.  Hence their name is `Restriction+A` and `Restriction+B` respectively.  Additionally the namespace containing `Restriction` must be included in the name.  For example if the namespace was `ConsoleApplication` you would need to use the name `ConsoleApplication.Restriction+A` as the name for `A`.

Comment: And this is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is a namespacing issue, try referencing the class types with:

```
Type typeRestriction = Type.GetType(string.Format("Restriction+{0}", RestrictionName));
```

Comment: I tried `Restriction+{0}` and `Restriction.{0}` but it did not work

Comment: It only misses the namespace. If this were to be used from another assembly, the fully qualified assembly name with version numbers and stuff would have to be in the string as well. But this is luckily not the case here.